# Android Remote Service without aidl?

Tags: android

Is it possible to write Remote Service in Android without aidl ?
If yes - is it better to use then aidl?

Comment: You're right... AIDL does suck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  If you want to write a remote service, you will -- at some level -- be using code very similar to AIDL.  While AIDL is used for generating the stubs and packaging data, you can also use a Messenger and Handler pair: but this is simply implemented on top of AIDL, so you're using it anyway.  For simple exchanges, a Messenger and Handler pair works, but for more complex situations using AIDL is appropriate.  If your question is whether there is a lighter communication mechanism (other than just Intents) than AIDL, the answer is no.